# Smoother object movement in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

I'm using this code in my script to move a gameobject:

```
void Update () {

    // Move the object forward along its z axis 1 unit/second.
    transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x , transform.position.y - 0.2f);

}
```

On screen the movement is a bit jaggy and not fluent.

Is there a different approach?

Hint: Please do not suggestion to use rigidbody functions since adding rigidbody would disrupt everything I did.

Can I use FxedUpdate?

Mirza

Comment: That is not unit/second. You'll need to multiply all your movements by Time.deltaTime

Comment: how is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Update` method and just multiply velocity with `Time.deltaTime`. But when you need more complex movement than "move on const velocity" better use both `Update` and `FixedUpdate`. Method `FixedUpdate` should chooses current velocity for object. For example, if you want to move object to specified position `FixedUpdate` method should calculates velocity depends on current object position and target position. Method `Update` in this case will be used for smoothing movement, it will not change real position of object but recalculates each time. Here example:

```
private Vector3 fixed_position;
private Vector3 velocity;

void FixedUpdate() {
    // apply previous velocity
    fixed_position += velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    // calculate new velocity
    velocity = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

void Update() {
    // recalculate smoothed position of object
    transform.position = fixed_position + velocity * (Time.time - Time.fixedTime);
}
```

Comment: transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x , transform.position.y - movespeed) * Time.deltaTime; does not work...it gives me odd results

Comment: ransform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - (movespeed * Time.deltaTime)); did the trick